# How to Show Three.js intellisense in a HTML File

Tags: html, three.js, intellisense

I've tried everything to get Three.js to show it's intellisense and it just will not show up.

Tried every trick in the book.

What am I missing here.

Please Advise.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/three.js"></script>
 <script>
     var x =  new THREE.
 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Three.js Intellisense Not Working]

Answer (score 2):

It seems this issue is the same as [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169330/vs-2017-javascript-intellisense-does-not-work.html).

Microsoft folks have created an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20993), but with no 
provided workaround.

You might want to keep an eye on that from time to time.
Meanwhile I propose you to switch to [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), while working with js projects.

You just have to install typings (npm install --save @types/three).